# Compiling JS values in CSS with webpack and CSS modules?

Tags: webpack

I'm using CSS Modules and have a JS file that holds my page's colors like so:

```
module.exports = {
  colors: {
    black: '#000000',
    white: '#ffffff',
    mint: '#b3e4e9',
    red: '#ed2e56'
  },
};
```

I'm able to extract the CSS and build it into it's own .css file and do the same with bundling my .js files. However, the color values are not compiled into their hex values, but rather maintain the name they are used in the exported JS object (for example, I'm getting 'background-color: ~colors.white', rather than 'background-color: #ffffff;' within my built .css file). Therefore, the styles aren't carrying through.

My webpack.prodution.config.js is setup like so:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const postCSS = require('./build/postcss');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, './public/build'),
    publicPath: '/build/',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel',
    }, {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css', 'postcss'),
    }, {
      test: /\.jpeg|jpg|gif|svg|png$/,
      loader: 'file?name=assets/images/[name].[ext]',
    }, {
      test: /\.ttf|woff|woff2|eot$/,
      loader: 'file?name=assets/fonts/[name].[ext]',
    }],
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css'),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compressor: { warnings: false },
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': JSON.stringify({
        NODE_ENV: 'development',
      }),
      __DEV__: true,
      __PROD__: false,
    }),
  ],
  postcss: function processPostCSS(bundler) {
    return postCSS(bundler);
  },
};
```

How can I separate my js and css into different pages while still having the JS colors compile to their hex values within the css? Thanks.